# For $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$, how would $\delta>0$ change after switching the interval $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

From Spivak's Calculus:

> Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. It is easy to see that, so long as $\epsilon < 1$, there will not be one $\delta > 0$ that works for these functions at all points $a$ in the open interval $(0,1)$.

In order to show that there will not be one $\delta > 0$ that works for these functions, I did:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \sin(\frac{1}{a})|\le \dfrac{|x-a|}{|x||a|}<\dfrac{2\delta}{a^{2}}$,

since $\biggl|\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \sin(\frac{1}{a}) \biggr|= 2\biggl|\cos\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{a}}{2}\sin\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{a}}{2}\biggr|=\biggl|2\cos\dfrac{\dfrac{x+a}{xa}}{2}\sin\dfrac{\dfrac{a-x}{xa}}{2}\biggr|$=

$2\biggl|\cos \dfrac{x+a}{2xa}\sin \dfrac{x-a}{2xa}\biggr|\le 2\biggl|\sin\dfrac{x-a}{2xa}\biggr|\le 2\dfrac{|x-a|}{2|xa|}=\dfrac{|x-a|}{|x||a|}$

Then by choosing $\delta < \dfrac{|a|}{2}$ and using the triangle inequality we get that $\dfrac{1}{|x||a|}<\dfrac{2}{a^{2}}$. Then $\delta = a^{2}\epsilon/2$ would mean that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$ If instead we considered points $a$ in the interval $(0,1]$, would there be any significant changes?

Comment: Nothing significant would change. The bad behavior occurs as you approach $x=0$, not $x=1$. By the way, you can establish your inequality $|\sin(u) - \sin(v)| \leq |u-v|$ more quickly if you have the mean value theorem available. (I'm not sure which chapter you're taking this from.)

Comment: How did you establish that $$\frac{|x-a|}{|x||a|} < \frac{2\delta}{a^2}?$$

Comment: $||x|-|a||<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $-\delta < |x|-|a|$ implies $-\delta + |a| < |x|$ and so $|x|>|a| -\delta > |a|/2$. Thus $1/|x|<2/|a|$ and $1/|x||a|<2/|a||a|=2/a^{2}$. Also, this is from the appendix of chapter 8 of the textbook.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the assumption that $\delta < |a|/2$. Your argument looks fine, and it works equally well if we change the interval to $(0,1]$. What **does** change things (probably Spivak covers this, I don't have my copy handy) is if you change the interval to $[c, 1)$ or $[c,1]$ where $c > 0$. In that case you will have uniform continuity.

Comment: More generally, if a function is continuous on a closed, bounded interval (i.e. a *compact* interval, but I think Spivak avoids using this word), then it is uniformly continuous on that interval (and on any subinterval of that interval, whether open or closed or half-open). This argument does not apply on $(0,1)$ because any closed, bounded interval containing $(0,1)$ must include $x=0$, and your function is not continuous at $x=0$.